# AWS APIGateway CORS for Lambda Proxy does not apply

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have set up a APIGateway resource with a `POST` Lambda Proxy method, and an `OPTIONS` method for CORS headers.

The `OPTIONS` method returns these headers:

```
$ curl -i -X OPTIONS https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/endpoint1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 18 Feb 2017 17:07:17 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId: xxxx
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,OPTIONS
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 xxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: xxxx==
```

Yet when I call the `POST` endpoint with the generated Javascript SDK, the Chrome browser console shows this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/endpoint1.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

as well as Firefox:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: 
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/endpoint1.
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Why is my CORS header not taken into account? Are additional changes of the POST method settings required?

Comment: You can't expect CORS to work with "localhost," presumably because that's fake and your browser knows it.  Test your site using `http://lvh.me` or `http://www.127.0.0.1.xip.io`.  These are aliases for localhost, but your browser doesn't know that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems to be required to add the headers manually in the lambda function.

In the case of NodeJS the script would look like this:

```
context.succeed({
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "X-Requested-With": '*',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,x-requested-with',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": 'POST,GET,OPTIONS'
    },
    "body": JSON.stringify(response)
})
```

Comment: @asdfasdfads Did you set the `OPTIONS` header response in the Gateway as well? This definitely worked for me, and considering the votes on this answer it must have worked for other people also.

Comment: worked for me thanks. was driving me nuts! i am using api gateway to trigger proxy lambda. i only added the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*' header to my lambda response and it worked!

Comment: Have a API GW proxy to Lambda integration. I had problems to get CORS working. So my solution was to send CORS headers from the backend, and remove "options" and "cors" in the Cloudformation template. It finally started to work after that.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to use the API Gateway to enrich the payload from your lambda with CORS related headers as described here: https://kennbrodhagen.net/2015/12/02/how-to-access-http-headers-using-aws-api-gateway-and-lambda/

This is a much more scalable and less error prone approach.

Comment: This method will not work when the API is in Proxy mode.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below points.

1. Did you deploy your updated API?
2. Did you create OPTIONS method for your API resource?
3. Did you add response headers for Method Response of OPTIONS method like below?

   - Access-Control-Allow-Headers
   - Access-Control-Allow-Methods
   - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
4. Did you perform 'Enable CORS' action on your API Resource?
5. After complete to check above, please check the Method Request of GET/POST Method of your API Resource. Perhaps, Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header was added automatically by API Gateway.

Thanks, 
Daniel